# sqlite3 regexp does match inverse character classes

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I designed a sqlite3 database with SQLiteStudio and DB Browser for SQLite. Both implement `REGEXP` through Qt regexp methods, which I use for queries and `CHECK` constraints.

I then proceeded to write a python script, which has to manually load a regexp extension, for which I experimented with the one in the `sqlite3-pcre` package and [the one given in the sqlite3 source code repository](https://www.sqlite.org/src/raw/ext/misc/regexp.c?name=a68d25c659bd2d893cd1215667bbf75ecb9dc7d4) (POSIX compliant apparently).

The latter would not match correctly inverted character groups, for example `regexp('[^a]', 'a')` would give a match, eventhough the only character in the string is an "a". Perhaps I'm missing something about beginning-of-line and end-of-line weirdness, but it looks like a bug to me?

The former would work as expected, but then cannot perform `pragma integrity_check;` because I have strings which are `NULL` (which is valid), but the pcre-regexp extension will complain with `error: no string` (which has been referenced in another comment on SO as a bug as well, which can be circumvented by checking first against `NOT NULL`).

My question therefore is:

1. Am I missing something about POSIX compliant regexp, that explains
   why the match returns true while it shouldn't?
2. Are there other regex
   extensions, that work better, especially with `NULL` strings.

Comment: You need to show your code if you expect anyone to help fix it.

Comment: @Barmar There is no code to be fixed. This is about standard (POSIX) regex syntax. I could provide an example, which would require that people download and compile their own version of sqlite3 regex extensions, because afaik there is no precompiled binaries for that and I doubt that anyone will go through that hassle anyway. the relevant regex patterns and test strings are given `regexp('[^a]' , 'a')`. the second question is also not code related.

Comment: It sounds like I misunderstood what you're doing. I thought you were writing your own SQLite extension to integrate Qt regexp methods.

Comment: Can your integrity check be `col IS NULL OR col regexp(...)`?

Comment: yes, that would be a workaround for the PCRE extension "bug", it's probably what I'll end up doing, but I was just wondering if my usage of the other extension was perhaps wrong. or if there are others I couldn't find.